# Filtering packages by their name from list out of file

Tags: file, powershell, filter, conditional-statements

I am trying to read program names from a file to filter out the installed ones.
For reading the file I got:
 `$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\Test.txt"`
Then I try to filter packages by their name which isnt working, what I tried:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object -Property Name -notin $file | select Name, IsFramework
```

or

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.Name -notin $file } | select Name, IsFramework
```

I cannot use any .Net statements, how can I solve this?

**Edit:** Here is my file's content:

```
Microsoft.BioEnrollment Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost windows.immersivecontrolpanel Microsoft.Windows.Cortana Microsoft.AccountsControl Microsoft.LockApp
```

Comment: Remove the `| Out-String`. You need the contents of the file as an array, not a single string.

Comment: Still not working, getting all the packages.

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Get-AppxPackage | ?{ $file.Contains($_.Name) } | select Name, IsFramework

Comment: @DavidBrabant thanks works!

Comment: Is the file content really just a single line?

Comment: Look up what -notin or -in does.  It would have to match an element or line on the right side exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to recap from [David Brabant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311712/david-brabant), the following worked for [askingQuestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7690416/askingquestions):

```
Get-AppxPackage | ?{ $file.Contains($_.Name) } | select Name, IsFramework
```

This works great and is probably one of the best ways to do this.

---

This didn't work for me for all applications, so here's another take at filtering the list. :)

*Matching Name:*

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -Like "appName"}
```

*Not Matching Name:*

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -NotMatch "appName"}
```

*Note that using Where-Object is not case sensitive but looks for exact match. On the flip side, you can also use wildcards.*

but to filter by file, you could do something like:

```
[string[]]$List = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\test.txt') -replace ' ',"`r`n"
 foreach ($ProgramName in $List)
 {
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -Like $ProgramName}
 }
```

*Note that `-replace ' ',"`r`n"` is only necessary for spaces between application names. You can just remove this and have each application on a new line. Also note that this could possibly produce duplicates.*

Wildcard Example:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -Like "*adobe*"}
```

Cheers!